# I need to organise the common Airflow Dag operators/tasks used by multiple dags in a single file, What is the best way of doing it?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I can import the class from another file and create operator in a dag, I can use a function from another file. But I need to keep the operators as a template to be used in many dags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to create a custom python library with your common operators/functions/tasks and [install it in your environment](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/plugins).

In the Dag documentation for composer, there are some [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#guidelines) and a useful [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#faqs) that could help you further decide the architecture.

Notice that the your custom libraries won't be stored in the dag bucket, they will be stored in a [bucket called "plugins"](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#top_of_page).